# Using mixins on Components with styled jsx in NextJS

Tags: sass, next.js, scss-mixins, styled-jsx

Can someone tell me how to use mixins on components in styled jsx? Whenever I try @include tablet{} I keep getting the "Error no mixin named tablet" error. It works on home.module.scss, but not for each individual component.